# Downloading and parsing JSON files to update ArrayAdapters on demand

Tags: java, android, json, multithreading, listview

Well I have an app set up, In way that there are, let's say, 3 ListViews in three different fragments.

Now a server provides 3 JSON files, that contain information, one for each ListView, which I have to parse into objects or lists of objects, and use them to instantiate my custom ArrayAdapters to display information on the list views.

The problem is that Downloading and parsing are operations that should happen outside the GUI thread.
So I am looking for the most effective way to update these list views on demand (when a fragment is inflated or OnResume etc)

What I've tried already was to download the needed json file using an IntentService then send the downloaded buffer to the GUI thread using a ResponseHandler and Intents, and then passing that to a manager class that was responsible for parsing the buffers into objects and populating the views. To do that, I had to keep the Views and the ArrayAdapters as properties to that class and provide on demand update methods.

Now my questions are:

1) Is it possible to have the service download the JSON files, parse them into collections and somehow send ArrayList objects to the GUI thread?

2) If I have to keep the adapters and update them in the GUI thread, what is the most effective (and maybe elegant way) to have a manager class keep and update the ListViews and their ArrayAdapters easily?(Do I have to get a new instance of the ArrayAdapter each time the information is updated, or can I update the inner ArrayList only?)

I think I won't include any code, since this is about the project structure and the preferred ways to do things.If it's needed for some parts though I can always edit the question later.